# ASUS laptop won't power on; what could have been the cause?

Tags: laptop-repair

I have an ASUS X53SC laptop which is only 5 months old. My laptop will not power on.

I gave the laptop to a service center and they said that my motherboard (mainly capacitors) was fried – they said they would replace the board. What would cause these capacitors to fail?

In fact I don't have a surge protector and the laptop came with only a 2-pin power cord – there is NO ground pin for it. Also, when I rest my palm on my laptop, I feel an electric shock.

Is this the cause for the capacitors failing? If so, I will ask the ASUS service center for a 3-pin power cord.

Answer (score 1):

Many computer manufacturers use low-quality capacitors on their mobos.  That said, it's more likely that you just got a lemon (unlucky!) and you had one with some issues...

If the capacitors that failed were in the power-regulating section, i.e. it conditions the power that comes from your power brick, I would say it could be possible that your power supply may have some issues.  More than likely though, you just got unlucky.

You *should* go grab a surge protector, however.  Your 3-pin power cord will not matter unless the grounding issue is *on the laptop,* but plugging your 2-pin into a grounded and protected surge protector will protect the laptop from lighting or random utility surges.

And, was your Asus not under warranty for this?  I do not think you should be paying a repair shop for something that should be covered...?

Comment: thank you for reply.my asus laptop is under warranty.as i am lucky that it is under warranty.and the service people said they will replace the motherboard.so i will get a surge protector.